# How to make a particular element null in a list

Tags: java, list, set, compare

I have a requirement to create a list from the existing list Existing List is row-1[d1,12,p1]row-2[d1,13,p1]row-3[d1,14,p1]row-4[d2,15,p2] row-5[d2,16,p2].In the new list I need to replace the p1 in the row-2 with null, and p2 in the row-5 with null means for any number of rows starting with d1, only the first row should have p1 and the rest of the rows the p1 should be null and the same goes with d2..dn.In the new list I need to make the second entry of the element P1 as null.

Comment: `list.set(1, null)`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your list looks like, but in general you can set an element to null by doing the following

If your existing list in java had the name list
i.e. `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();`

then you can make an element null by the following command
`list.set(i, null)`
Where i is the index you are looking at.

If you're having trouble knowing how to do something in java, I recommend looking at the javadocs, in this case I looked at the javadocs for ArrayList. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: Existing List is  
row-1 { d1 12  p1  } 
row-2  { d1 13  p1 }
row-3  {d1 14  p1}
row-4  {d2 15  p2}
row-5  {d2 16 p2}  in the new list I need to replace the p1 in the row-2 with null, and p2 in the row -5 with null means for any number of rows starting with d1, only the first row should have p1 and the rest of the rows the p1 should be null and the same goes with d2..dn.